# Cocoa - weak linking against framework - ignoring version?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

We have a Cocoa app that makes use of the R framework. Our intention is NOT to ship R with the app, as users will likely have their own version installed locally. The question we have is how to properly weak link against a framework that has multiple versions.

We're weak linking against it:

- Framework set to `optional` in linked binaries
- Added as `-weak_framework` in build settings > other linker flags
- We do the usual "class exists" detection in code before attempting to use R.

Here's what happens:

- If the same version of R we linked against is installed, everything works fine.
- If R is not installed, everything is fine. We detect the absence and it gracefully fails.
- Our trouble is when we link against a version (let's say 3.1) and the user has a different version (let's say 3.2). Then we get the error `can't resolve symbol (some sybmol) in (my app) because dependent dylib #1 could not be loaded`.

I guess this makes sense as we built against 3.1 and it's not there - 3.2 is. I'm just unclear on how to approach properly weak linking against an external library like this and allowing it to work with a different version. Or I'm completely missing the boat on how to weak link entirely. Which is entirely possible.

Any guidance very much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@eww and I have continued investigating this, and here's what we were able to find.  When the framework and application are being compiled, they are referencing a specific version of R.framework.  We were able to see this by running:

```
otool -L /Applications/StatTag.app/Contents/Frameworks/RCocoa.framework/RCocoa 
/Applications/StatTag.app/Contents/Frameworks/RCocoa.framework/RCocoa:
  @rpath/RCocoa.framework/Versions/A/RCocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
  **/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/lib/libR.dylib (compatibility version 3.3.0, current version 3.3.2)**
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1252.0.0)
  /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
  /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1225.1.1)
  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1253.0.0)
```

After some searching, [this post](http://thecourtsofchaos.com/2013/09/16/how-to-copy-and-relink-binaries-on-osx/) came up which clued us in on how to change the R.framework reference to be "Current" instead of the specific version

```
install_name_tool -change /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/lib/libR.dylib /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/lib/libR.dylib /Applications/StatTag.app/Contents/Frameworks/RCocoa.framework/RCocoa
```

We can see now that it's referencing the Current version folder:

```
otool -L /Applications/StatTag.app/Contents/Frameworks/RCocoa.framework/RCocoa 
/Applications/StatTag.app/Contents/Frameworks/RCocoa.framework/RCocoa:
  @rpath/RCocoa.framework/Versions/A/RCocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
  /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/lib/libR.dylib (compatibility version 3.3.0, current version 3.3.2)
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1252.0.0)
  /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
  /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1225.1.1)
  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1253.0.0)
```

What tripped us up a little more is when this gets built into our final application, there are other local frameworks referencing RCocoa and R, which meant we had to run install_name_tool multiple times.  Happy to report things are now working.